# Rails - Clearance engine - installation issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, clearance

The installation for clearance seems very straight forward (https://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance). I'm following in the instructions, although I'm getting an error almost immediately.

On the the fifth step "rake db:migrate"

I get the following error:

```
rake aborted!
undefined method `configure' for Clearance:Module
```

I have no idea what I should be doing differently?

Thanks in advance!

-Elliot

updating with added trace

```
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
undefined method `configure' for Clearance:Module
/Users/elliot/work/liftrr/config/initializers/clearance.rb:1
/Users/elliot/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:145:in `load_without_new_constant_marking'
/Users/elliot/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:145:in `load'
/Users/elliot/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/Users/elliot/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:145:in `load'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:622:in `load_application_initializers'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:621:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:621:in `load_application_initializers'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:176:in `process'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
/Users/elliot/work/liftrr/config/environment.rb:9
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/Users/elliot/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/Users/elliot/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/Users/elliot/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/tasks/misc.rake:4
/Users/elliot/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `call'
/Users/elliot/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `execute'
/Users/elliot/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `each'
/Users/elliot/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `execute'
/Users/elliot/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:597:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/Users/elliot/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/elliot/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:607:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/elliot/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:604:in `each'
/Users/elliot/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:604:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/elliot/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:596:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/Users/elliot/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/elliot/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:583:in `invoke'
/Users/elliot/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2051:in `invoke_task'
/Users/elliot/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/Users/elliot/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `each'
/Users/elliot/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/Users/elliot/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/elliot/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2023:in `top_level'
/Users/elliot/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2001:in `run'
/Users/elliot/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/elliot/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
/Users/elliot/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31
/usr/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/bin/rake:19
```

Comment: Which Rails and clearance version ?

Comment: RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '2.3.5'

I assume its the latest version of clearance - in the installtion it says to put :version 0.8.2 in the gem config file, so I assume thats it? 

I'm pretty new to rails btw, if it wasn't obvious enough

Comment: Can you put your complete backtrace with --trace in your rake command ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the installation wiki was outdated. It has since been updated.